# Get number from URL string

Tags: regex, scala

So i have this `URL`

```
val url = "bla_bla/5555/review"
```

And i want to get the number `5555`.
This is what i have try:

```
val spl = url.split("/")
val number = spl(spl.length - 2)
```

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Why not use [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)?

Comment: i didn't familiar with that, any example ?

Comment: Does your code work alright? -> No - ask a question on SO. Yes, but I want to enhance it -> ask at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val url = "bla_bla/5555/review"
val pattern = "[0-9]+".r
```

To find a single match, you can do

```
pattern.findFirstMatchIn(url)
```

For more than one match, you can do

```
 pattern.findAllMatchIn(url)
```